# Create right and left side vertical line of the page - Android Java iTextPdf

Tags: java, android, itext

I need to create a vertical line on the right and left side of the page, just in the dimension I defined, it cannot be on the entire page. two vertical lines covering 80% of the page.

[image]

This line cannot be fixed, as the receipt may have a list of products.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solution.

```
 Rectangle small = new Rectangle(292, 720);
        Font smallfont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10);
        Font boldfont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, Font.BOLD);

        Document document = new Document(small, 5, 5, 15, 5);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        document.open();
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.setTotalWidth(new float[]{ 160, 120 });
        table.setLockedWidth(true);

// first row
        PdfPCell cell
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("item1", boldfont));
        cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT);
        cell.setPadding(5);
        table.addCell(cell);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("item2", smallfont));
        cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        cell.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT);
        cell.setBorder(Rectangle.RIGHT);
        cell.setPadding(5);
        table.addCell(cell);
```

cell.setBorder defines the border.

cell.setBorder (Rectangle.LEFT) or cell.setBorder (Rectangle.RIGHT)
or cell.setBorder (Rectangle.LEFT | Rectangle.RIGHT);